# asyncio: Is it possible to cancel a future been run by an Executor?

Tags: python, executor, event-loop, python-asyncio

I would like to start a blocking function in an Executor using the asyncio call loop.run_in_executor and then cancel it later, but that doesn't seem to be working for me.

Here is the code:

```
import asyncio
import time

from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor


def blocking_func(seconds_to_block):
    for i in range(seconds_to_block):
        print('blocking {}/{}'.format(i, seconds_to_block))
        time.sleep(1)

    print('done blocking {}'.format(seconds_to_block))


@asyncio.coroutine
def non_blocking_func(seconds):
    for i in range(seconds):
        print('yielding {}/{}'.format(i, seconds))
        yield from asyncio.sleep(1)

    print('done non blocking {}'.format(seconds))


@asyncio.coroutine
def main():
    non_blocking_futures = [non_blocking_func(x) for x in range(1, 4)]
    blocking_future = loop.run_in_executor(None, blocking_func, 5)
    print('wait a few seconds!')
    yield from asyncio.sleep(1.5)

    blocking_future.cancel()
    yield from asyncio.wait(non_blocking_futures)



loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=1)
loop.set_default_executor(executor)
asyncio.async(main())
loop.run_forever()
```

I would expect the code above to only allow the blocking function to output:

```
blocking 0/5
blocking 1/5
```

and then see the output of the non blocking function. But instead the blocking future continues on even after I have canceled.

Is it possible? Is there some other way of doing it?

Thanks

**Edit:** More discussion on running blocking and non-blocking code using asyncio: [How to interface blocking and non-blocking code with asyncio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23898363/how-to-interface-blocking-and-non-blocking-code-with-asyncio)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

In this case, there is no way to cancel the `Future` once it has actually started running, because you're relying on the behavior of `concurrent.futures.Future`, and [its docs state the following](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Future.cancel):

> **`cancel()`**
>
> Attempt to cancel the call. **If the call is currently being executed
>   and cannot be cancelled then the method will return `False`**, otherwise
>   the call will be cancelled and the method will return `True`.

So, the only time the cancellation would be successful is if the task is still pending inside of the `Executor`. Now, you're actually using an `asyncio.Future` wrapped around a `concurrent.futures.Future`, and in practice the `asyncio.Future` returned by `loop.run_in_executor()` will raise a `CancellationError` if you try to `yield from` it after you call `cancel()`, even if the underlying task is actually already running. But, it won't *actually* cancel the execution of the task inside the `Executor`.

If you need to actually cancel the task, you'll need to use a more conventional method of interrupting the task running in the thread. The specifics of how you do that is use-case dependent. For the use-case you presented in the example, you could use a `threading.Event`:

```
def blocking_func(seconds_to_block, event):
    for i in range(seconds_to_block):
        if event.is_set():
            return
        print('blocking {}/{}'.format(i, seconds_to_block))
        time.sleep(1)

    print('done blocking {}'.format(seconds_to_block))


...
event = threading.Event()
blocking_future = loop.run_in_executor(None, blocking_func, 5, event)
print('wait a few seconds!')
yield from asyncio.sleep(1.5)

blocking_future.cancel()  # Mark Future as cancelled
event.set() # Actually interrupt blocking_func
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The solution you suggest sounds good for solving this case.

My issue is that the blocking_func is in a 3rd party in my real life case.

I am going to wait for a day or two to see if anyone has any further suggestions; otherwise I will mark your answer as accepted.

Comment: Do you know how can I add a callback to the blocking_func on completion?

Comment: @dano I tried the way you cancelled this code, but it seems hanging. I have asked a question regarding this here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72542334/cancel-run-in-executor-coroutine-from-the-main-thread-not-working

Answer (score 2):

As threads share the same memory address space of a process, there is no safe way to terminate a running thread. This is the reason why most programming languages do not allow to kill running threads (there are lots of ugly hacks around this limitation).

Java learnt it the [hard way](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/misc/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html).

A solution would consist in running your function in a separate process instead of a thread and terinate it gracefully.

The [Pebble](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pebble) library offers an interface similar to `concurrent.futures` supporting running `Futures` to be cancelled.

```
from pebble import ProcessPool

def function(foo, bar=0):
    return foo + bar

with ProcessPool() as pool:
    future = pool.schedule(function, args=[1])

    # if running, the container process will be terminated 
    # a new process will be started consuming the next task
    future.cancel()
```