# asyncio.TimeoutError is never raised

Tags: python, python-3.4, python-asyncio

I want to test how `asyncio` handle blocking processes.

There must be something wrong with my code because `asyncio.TimeoutError` is never raised:

```
import asyncio, random, time

q = asyncio.Queue()

MAX_WAIT = 5

@asyncio.coroutine
def blocking_task(sec):
    print('This task will sleep {} sec.'.format(sec))
    time.sleep(sec)

@asyncio.coroutine
def produce():
    while True:
        q.put_nowait(random.randint(1,10))
        yield from asyncio.sleep(0.5 + random.random())

@asyncio.coroutine
def consume():
    while True:
        value = yield from q.get()
        try:
            yield from asyncio.wait_for(blocking_task(value), MAX_WAIT)
        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            print('~/~ Job has been canceled !!')
        else:
            print('=/= Job has been done :]')


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
asyncio.ensure_future(produce())
asyncio.ensure_future(consume())
loop.run_forever()
```

This code produce the following output:

```
$ ./tst3.py 
This task will sleep 2 sec.
=/= Job has been done :]
This task will sleep 1 sec.
=/= Job has been done :]
This task will sleep 7 sec.
=/= Job has been done :]
```

Answer (score 2):

> Use `asyncio.sleep` instead of `sleep`

The [TimeoutError of asyncio](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#timeouterror) is different from [buildin TimeoutError](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#TimeoutError). That's why you can not use time.sleep to trigger this error. For triggering TimeoutError in asyncio.coroutine, you only can use timer which is implemented by asyncio module.

```
@asyncio.coroutine
def blocking_task(sec):
    print('This task will sleep {} sec.'.format(sec))
    yield from asyncio.sleep(sec)
```

**Result**

```
This task will sleep 10 sec.
~/~ Job has been canceled !!
This task will sleep 3 sec.
=/= Job has been done :]
This task will sleep 4 sec.
=/= Job has been done :]
This task will sleep 2 sec.
=/= Job has been done :]
This task will sleep 7 sec.
~/~ Job has been canceled !!
This task will sleep 2 sec.
=/= Job has been done :]
```

Comment: What if there was other long running blocking function (not sleep), how would I ensure it's cancelled after 5 sec?

Comment: @NarūnasK Have a look at [loop.run_in_executor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.AbstractEventLoop.run_in_executor) and this [answer about canceling a blocking call running in an executor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26413613/asyncio-is-it-possible-to-cancel-a-future-been-run-by-an-executor#26414982).