# Why ThreadPoolExecutor ignoring exceptions?

Tags: python, concurrency, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading, threadpoolexecutor

I have a code like this:

```
from concurrent.futures.thread import ThreadPoolExecutor
from time import sleep


def foo(message, time):
    sleep(time)
    print('Before exception in ' + message)
    raise Exception('OOOPS! EXCEPTION IN ' + message)
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=2)
    future1 = executor.submit(foo, 'first', 1)
    future2 = executor.submit(foo, 'second', 3)
    print(future1.result())
    print(future2.result())
```

And when I run this, I get the following as a result:

```
Before exception in first
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
  File "...", line 8, in foo
    raise Exception('OOOPS! EXCEPTION IN ' + message)
Exception: OOOPS! EXCEPTION IN first
Before exception in second

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Why is the second exception being ignored? I want to catch and handle exceptions on each of the threads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because exception **is raised** by `result()` and prevents normal script flow. To see the second exception you need to catch the first one:

```
    executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=2)
    future1 = executor.submit(foo, 'first', 1)
    future2 = executor.submit(foo, 'second', 3)
    try:
        print(future1.result())
    except:
        pass
    print(future2.result())
```

Comment: And how can I stop a executor if an exception occurs in at least one of the threads

Comment: Perhaps it will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62474014/python-threadpoolexecutor-terminate-all-threads/62497987