# Terminate executor using ThreadPoolExecutor from concurrent.futures module

Tags: python, multithreading, concurrency, threadpool, python-multithreading

I am trying to terminate a ThreadPool based on values returned from long running request. I wish to terminate the ThreadPool once the sum of the request return values reaches MIN_REQUIRED_VALUE

I am sure the problem is that I am creating a full list of futures which will always have to be resolved. I am not sure how to perform the requests without creating a list with ThreadPoolExecutor

I know there has been a couple of questions related to terminating a thread pool. I have found similar questions but the answers don't seem to handle the return value.

Smilar questions:

- [Python ThreadPoolExecutor terminate all threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62474014/python-threadpoolexecutor-terminate-all-threads)
- [asyncio: Is it possible to cancel a future been run by an Executor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26413613/asyncio-is-it-possible-to-cancel-a-future-been-run-by-an-executor)

If there is a better way to do this with another module, that would be fine.

Any assistance would be much appreciated.

```py
from time import sleep
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, as_completed

NUM_REQUESTS = 50
MIN_REQUIRED_VALUE = 30


def long_request(id):
    sleep(3)
    return {"data": {"value": 10}}


def check_results(results):
    total = 0
    for result in results:
        total += result["data"]["value"]

    return total


def main():
    futures = []
    responses = []

    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as executor:
        for request_index in range(NUM_REQUESTS):
            future = executor.submit(long_request, request_index)

            # Create Futures List
            futures.append(future)

        for future in as_completed(futures):
            responses.append(future.result())

            # Check minimum value reached
            total = check_results(responses)
            if total > MIN_REQUIRED_VALUE:
                executor.shutdown(wait=False)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

I changed the code around to append only futures with results if MIN_REQUIRED_VALUE not reached and loop through all pending futures and cancel them if MIN_REQUIRED_VALUE is reached.

You can notice I added num_requests to check number of requests submitted and it turns out to be exactly 6 in this case which is expected.

If anyone has a better way to do this would be good to see.

```py
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, as_completed
from time import sleep

NUM_REQUESTS = 1000
MIN_REQUIRED_VALUE = 50


def long_request(id):
    sleep(1)
    return {"data": {"value": 10}}


def check_results(results):
    total = 0
    for result in results:
        total += result["data"]["value"]

    return total


def main():
    futures = []
    responses = []
    num_requests = 0

    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as executor:
        for request_index in range(NUM_REQUESTS):
            future = executor.submit(long_request, request_index)

            # Future list
            futures.append(future)

        for future in as_completed(futures):

            # --- Changed Logic Below ---
            total = check_results(responses)

            if total > MIN_REQUIRED_VALUE:
                for pending_future in futures:
                    pending_future.cancel()
            else:
                num_requests += 1
                responses.append(future.result())

    return num_requests


if __name__ == "__main__":
    requests = main()
    print("Num Requests: ", requests)
```

Comment: @gold_cy you are correct, executor.shutdown(wait=False) works fine now. I was trying that in the beginning and abandoned it because it was not working with my first logic. I tried it with the second logic and it works. It must be doing something similar to looping over incomplete futures and calling cancel