Why can't ThreadPoolExecutor timeout a long running expression?
I have a function that contains the output from calculating a huge number. This function is bound to a decorator that is supposed to abort the calculation after a few seconds:
import concurrent.futures
import functools

executor = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=1)

def with_timeout(timeout_seconds: int = 10):
    """
    Decorator to add a timeout to a function.
    """
    def decorator(function):
        @functools.wraps(function)
        def timed_function(*args, **kwargs):
            error_message = f"Function {function.__name__!r} timed out after {timeout_seconds} seconds."
            future = executor.submit(function, *args, **kwargs)
            try:
                return future.result(timeout=timeout_seconds)
            except concurrent.futures.TimeoutError as exc:
                raise TimeoutError(error_message) from exc
        return timed_function
    return decorator

@with_timeout(timeout_seconds=2)
def calculate_large_number():
    """
    Calculate a large number.
    """
    # time.sleep(10)
    return 10 ** 10 ** 10

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        result = calculate_large_number()
        print(f"Result: {result}")
    except (TimeoutError, Exception) as e:
        print(f"Error: {e}")`

If you comment out the time.sleep line, the function gets properly interrupted. But once it hits the 10 ** 10 ** 10 calculation, which is effectively infinite, it doesn't interrupt and keeps hanging.
Why can't ThreadPoolExecutor interrupt a running expression?

Can you use that with_timeout with a function that only contains sleep(15)? And a timeout lower than the sleep.

If I add a wait to the calculation function in the form: time.sleep(3), then I will get the output: "Error: Function 'calculate_large_number' timed out after 2 seconds". And this signals that the code is working properly, but when I try to do what I covered in the topic, I don’t get any output

As I said, try to do @with_timeout(timeout_seconds=2) and in the function sleep(5), when do you get the output, after 2 seconds or after 5 seconds.

Daviid, as I showed above, the code executes perfectly if I set more expected in the function(time.sleep(n+1) than I set in the decorator

Threads don't work like that. Use processes if you need killable workers.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75310731/how-to-exit-threadpoolexecutor-with-statement-immediately-when-a-future-is-runni : As you can see only three of tasks are done. ThreadPoolExecutor actually based on threading module and Thread in Python can't be stopped in some conventional way. Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323972/is-there-any-way-to-kill-a-thread

If I understand your post, there are a couple issues involved here. First, let's rewrite the code to not use a decorator. Not only will it make it easier to understand what is going on, it will be necessary when I swap in a multiprocessing pool for a multithreading pool (because the code will not work on platforms that use the spawn method to create child processes, e.g. Windows).
Here the worker function is just sleeping instead of calculating a large number:
import concurrent.futures
import time

def run_a_long_time():
    time.sleep(10)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    executor = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=1)

    t0 = time.time()
    future = executor.submit(run_a_long_time)

    try:
        result = future.result(timeout=2)
        print(f"Result: {result}")
    except concurrent.futures.TimeoutError:
        print(f"Timeout!")

    # Wait for all tasks to complete:
    executor.shutdown(wait=True)

    print('Total elapsed time: ', time.time() - t0)

Prints:
Timeout!
Total elapsed time:  10.001061916351318

So even though we get the timeout exception, the actual running task is not terminated and continues to run. If we explicitly wait for the running task to complete by calling executor.shutdown(wait=True), then the final elapsed time message will clearly show that 10 seconds will have elapsed. If I change this to executor.shutdown(wait=False), then the elapsed time message will naturally display after ~2 seconds. But the actual program will not terminate for another 8 seconds. So when you say "the function gets interrupted" I interpret that to mean you are saying that the worker function run__long_time gets interrupted (halted), but that is just not so.
A second issue is that, unlike a process, there is no way to terminate a thread without its cooperation (for example, setting a stop flag that the thread periodically checks and terminates if it is set). However, there is another pooling package you can use, i.e.multiprocessing. This works differently than concurrent.futures in that you can call terminate on the pool and then even running tasks will be instantly killed as long as it is a multiprocessing pool we are using and not a multithreading pool.
from multiprocessing.pool import Pool
# To use a multithreading pool: from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool

import time

def run_a_long_time():
    # Compute a large number
    return 10 ** 10 ** 10

if __name__ == "__main__":
    pool = Pool(processes=1)

    t0 = time.time()
    async_result = pool.apply_async(run_a_long_time)

    try:
        result = async_result.get(timeout=2)
        print(f"Result: {result}")
    except multiprocessing.TimeoutError:
        print(f"Timeout!")

    # Kill the pool and any running tasks:
    pool.terminate()

    print('Total elapsed time: ', time.time() - t0)

Prints:
Timeout!
Total elapsed time:  2.025102853775024

And the program actually does terminate within ~2 seconds.
If you want to be able to truly interrupt a submitted task so that its execution is halted, that task must be running either in a separate multiprocessing.Process instance on which you call the terminate method or as a task submitted to a multiprocessing pool. But in the latter case you must call terminate on the pool, which results in killing any other running tasks.
