# How to gracefully end asyncio program with CTRL-C when using loop run_in_executor

Tags: python, python-asyncio

The following code requires 3 presses of CTRL-C to end, how can I make it end with one only? (So it works nicely in Docker)

```py
import asyncio
import time


def sleep_blocking():
    print("Sleep blocking")
    time.sleep(1000)


async def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    await loop.run_in_executor(None, sleep_blocking)


try:
    asyncio.run(main())
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("Nicely shutting down ...")
```

I've read many asyncio related questions and answers but can't figure this one out yet. The 1st CTRL-C does nothing, the 2nd prints "Nicely shutting down ..." and then hangs. The 3rd CTRL-C prints an ugly error.

I'm on Python 3.9.10 and Linux.

(edit: updated code per comment @mkrieger1)

Comment: What happens if you replace `loop.run_until_complete(loop.run_in_executor(...))` by `await loop.run_in_executor(...)`?

Comment: @mkrieger1 then it requires 3 CTRL-Cs :) Really. The 1st doesn't do anything it seems, the 2nd prints `"Nicely shutting down ..."` and the 3rd the ugly error again

Answer (score 1):

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26413613/asyncio-is-it-possible-to-cancel-a-future-been-run-by-an-executor) we know that it's effectively impossible to kill a task running in a thread executor. If I replace the default thread executor with a `ProcessPoolExecutor`, I get the behavior you're looking for.  Here's the code:

```
import concurrent.futures
import asyncio
import time


def sleep_blocking():
    print("Sleep blocking")
    time.sleep(1000)


async def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    x = concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor()
    await loop.run_in_executor(x, sleep_blocking)


try:
    asyncio.run(main())
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("Nicely shutting down ...")
```

And the result is:

```
$ python asynctest.py
Sleep blocking
^CNicely shutting down ...
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. But ... my non-contrived real code actually was also using `asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe` which doesn't work from another process.

Comment: You may want to consider updating your question with example code that reproduces the problem you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 1):

The way to exit immediately and unconditionally from a Python program is by calling os._exit().  If your background threads are in the middle of doing something important this may not be wise.  However the following program does what you asked (python 3.10, Windows10):

```
import asyncio
import time
import os


def sleep_blocking():
    print("Sleep blocking")
    time.sleep(1000)


async def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(loop.run_in_executor(None, sleep_blocking))


try:
    asyncio.run(main())
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("Nicely shutting down ...")
    os._exit(42)
```

Comment: Does the `42` mean anything specific other than "not 0"?

Comment: No, the function has to get an integer argument.  So I picked a famous one.

Comment: So simple .... great! Question, I see this in the `os` docs: `The standard way to exit is sys.exit(n). _exit() should normally only be used in the child process after a fork().` Any reason you recommend os._exit?

Comment: Answer to my question: `sys.exit(42)` doesn't end the program, it hangs and still requires multiple CTRL-Cs

Comment: Right.  sys.exit() will block until all the secondary, non-daemon threads have closed.  I couldn't see any way to mark your secondary threads as daemon since they are created by multiprocessing.Pool, and it doesn't give you that possibility.