# Cancel run_in_executor coroutine from the main thread not working

Tags: python, multithreading, python-asyncio

In my use case I ping to an service while a sync operation is occurring. Once the sync operation is finished I need to to stop the ping operation, but it seems `run_in_executor` is not able to `cancel`

```
import asyncio
import threading

async def running_bg(loop, event):
    await loop.run_in_executor(None, running, loop, event)

def running(loop, event):
    while True:
        if event.is_set():
            print("cancelling")
            break
        print("We are in running")
        future = asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(asyncio.sleep(5), loop)
        future.result()
    return

async def run_them(steps, loop):
    step = steps
    event = threading.Event()
    task = loop.create_task(running_bg(loop, event))
    while steps:
        await asyncio.sleep(2)
        steps -= 1
    event.set()
    task.cancel() # if I comment this, it works well, but if I dont, then it hangs
    try:
        await task
    except asyncio.CancelledError:
        print("task cancelled")
    return


if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(run_them(3, loop))
```

When I call `cancel()` it hangs in the terminal with:

```bash
We are in running
We are in running
task cancelled
^CError in atexit._run_exitfuncs:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 40, in _python_exit
    t.join()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 1011, in join
    self._wait_for_tstate_lock()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 1027, in _wait_for_tstate_lock
    elif lock.acquire(block, timeout):
KeyboardInterrupt
```

But When I dont call the `cancel()` it works fine with the `threading.Event` flag.

```bash
We are in running
We are in running
cancelling
```

I know we dont need to cancel the if we have an event flag, but I saw this example from a [different answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26414982/4693568).

So why does the program hangs, any possible reason?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is related to the fact that your `running` method, which executes in the `asyncio` default thread pool, is calling back into the asyncio event loop thread and waiting for a result. In your example code, you're letting the `run_them` function exit immediately after you cancel the Task, which immediately shuts down your event loop. When the event loop shuts down, it means any outstanding coroutines do not complete.

This means your event loop shuts down before your `running` method receives the result from its `future.result()` call, which is waiting on an `asyncio.sleep(5)` call that will never complete. That means `future.result()` never returns, which leaves the `running` method hanging, which means the `ThreadPoolExecutor` it is running in can't shutdown. This is what prevents your application from exiting. Note how the stack trace you get when you Ctrl+C starts in the `concurrent.futures` library - that's where it waits for the `ThreadPoolExecutor` to shut down.

If you're using Python 3.9+, you should be able to fix this by adding a call to `await loop.shutdown_default_executor()` at the end of your `run_them` method. If you're using an earlier version, you have to basically implement that method yourself:

```
def shutdown(fut, loop):
    try:
        loop._default_executor.shutdown(wait=True)
    finally:
        loop.call_soon_threadsafe(fut.set_result, None)


async def run_them(steps, loop):
    step = steps
    event = threading.Event()
    task = loop.create_task(running_bg(loop, event))
    while steps:
        await asyncio.sleep(2)
        steps -= 1
    event.set()
    task.cancel()
    try:
        await task
    except asyncio.CancelledError:
        print("task cancelled")
    # Wait for the default thread pool to shut down before exiting
    fut = loop.create_future()
    t = threading.Thread(target=shutdown, args=(fut, loop))
    t.start()
    await fut
    t.join()
```

Alternatively, you could just not call task.cancel() and rely on the `Event()` to break out of the `running` method.

Comment: I just added a `await asyncio.sleep(5)` after the print statement, it cancelled properly. I understood your explanation really well.

Comment: @Ja8zyjits that works, though it's not the most efficient. Could you just call `time.sleep(5)` inside `running`, so you don't depend on the event loop thread inside your worker pool thread? I'd say in general having a call chain of event loop thread -> worker pool thread -> event loop thread should be avoided.

Comment: yes, will keep that in mind.