# Python: Asyncio run_in_executor futures can't be cancelled

Tags: python, task, python-asyncio, event-loop

So I use the **`.run_in_executor()`** method of the event loop to create a new process to perform my method:

```py
executor = ProcessPoolExecutor(5)
list_of_futures = []

def run_in_another_process(func: Callable, *args, **kwargs) -> asyncio.Future:
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    future = loop.run_in_executor(executor=executor, func=functools.partial(func, *args, **kwargs))
    list_of_futures.append(future)
    return future
```

And it works fine. But when I try to cancel a future using **`cancel()`** method, it just does nothing, even though it's marked as *canceled*:

```py
list_of_futures[0].cancel()

# True, but it's still in the RAM and is being performed!
list_of_futures[0].cancelled()
```

So the question is, how to cancel `asyncio.Future` properly? Why default method doesn't work?

Comment: Does this answer your question? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26413613/asyncio-is-it-possible-to-cancel-a-future-been-run-by-an-executor

Comment: Absolutely!
Thank you so much, don't know how I didn't manage to find that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [asyncio: Is it possible to cancel a future been run by an Executor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26413613/asyncio-is-it-possible-to-cancel-a-future-been-run-by-an-executor)