# Using asyncio with blocking code

Tags: python, iterator, python-asyncio

Firstly, I looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23898363/how-to-interface-blocking-and-non-blocking-code-with-asyncio), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28492103/how-to-combine-python-asyncio-with-threads) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23898363/how-to-interface-blocking-and-non-blocking-code-with-asyncio) and whilst the first has some useful information, it's not relevant here because I'm trying to iterate over values.

Here's an example of something I want to be able to do:

```python
class BlockingIter:
    def __iter__(self):
        while True:
            yield input()

async def coroutine():
    my_iter = BlockingIter()
    #Magic thing here
    async for i in my_iter:
        await do_stuff_with(i)
```

How would I go about this?

(Note, `BlockingIter` is in reality a library I'm using ([chatexchange](https://github.com/Manishearth/ChatExchange)) so there might be a few other complications.)

Comment: Can you say more about the behavior you want here: is `do_stuff_with(i)` the only part you want done asynchronously?

Comment: No, I'm working in a framework that uses asyncio as a base and I've got to work with it

Comment: Well, you could probably use `run_in_executor` to advance an iterator object. So `await`ing `loop.run_in_executor(None, next, it)` in a loop would be reasonably close to the desired behaviour.

Comment: @vaultah that works, thanks! If you want to write an answer, the final code is `iter_messages = iter(my_iter);while 1:;i = await loop.run_in_executor(None, next, iter_messages)`

Comment: I think a better question is "how do I get user input asynchronously"

Comment: That's not what I wanted but it worked as a minimal example of what would cause the problem I was getting

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @vaultah says and also explained in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#executor), `awaiting` the `executor` (`await loop.run_in_executor(None, next, iter_messages)`) is probably what you want.